# A simple pulse generator

Tags: diodes, generator, pulse, tvs

Basically, I want a minimalistic pulse generator. I guess I've always like the idea of Avalanche Breakdown to do this. I was trying to do this by using 2N2222's in reverse breakdown mode, [link here](http://cappels.org/dproj/simplest_LED_flasher/Simplest_LED_Flasher_Circuit.html), but I was largely disappointed with the non-steep turn ons. By that I mean, as the capacitor charges, the load (the LED) already gets a voltage difference. I wanted a steep turn on, as if a mechanical switch has been flicked or a hi-edge square wave from a 555 or something like that.

So now, I've fallen back to using Avalanche Diodes instead of avalanching transistors. I know that Zeners rated at 5.5V and up are generally Avalanche Diodes, so i went for them (using a 1N4735 that I have (@ 6.2V), but below I'm using a 1N4736 (@ 6.8V)). There was a marked improvement. It's almost like the 1N4735 has to have 1/2 of it's rated voltage before there was any difference in the load (R3 + D2), which grew as the capacitor charged to full.

My initial mod is as shown below and I've tried several other variations, but all it does is a delayed turn on and stays that way. Even the turn on is not very steep (grew as the capacitor charged to full). I could only guess that the current from the source dropped by R1 is feeding the load, which means the capacitor has not been fully discharged to allow cutoff to the Avalanche diode. Or, perhaps, the Avalanche Diode's cutoff current is very low, so it's keeping the transistor conducting. I'm not really sure.

I then noticed that there are TVS Diodes that can avalanche at relatively low voltages (3V or so), much lower than the normal Avalanche Diode's 5.5V, labeled as Zeners. I also hope it avalanches steeply. I'm also hoping the "Reverse Standoff Voltage" parameter will act as an effective cutoff when the voltage falls a certain level...

So can I use TVS Diodes like [these](http://www.bourns.com/data/global/pdfs/CDSOT23-SLVU2.8.pdf)?

Or maybe there is just a fundamental mistake in my mod??

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYuQx3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: As mentioned below, the diagram above is wrong. The Avalanche Diode is supposed to be in reverse bias.

Comment: somebody please answer my question... i honestly don't know for sure if this works until i order the parts (the TVS diode)... and, i don't want to order it just to find out it doesn't work at all...

Comment: If you're putting yourself through all of this for the sake of learning, that's admirable; but if what you really want is a simple pulse generator that just works, why not use a 555?

Comment: because i want a compact solution... and there's other things i want to use this for...

Comment: 555 is compact :) and you can use 555 for a lot of things as well.

Comment: to do this with a 555 requires 2 more resistors, a capacitor, a diode and probably a coupling cap for pin 5. total of 6 components. ok so this is marginally better, by having 1 less component (the low duty resistor). as for controlling the length of low duty, then i suppose it's t1=R1*C. the length of high pulse is t2=R3*C (ok, so having to consider R3 might count as 6 components as well, but it depends on the impedance of load, really). also, no ln(2) or ln(3).. and, this has a much higher voltage range (555 being only 4-18V).

Comment: just please tell me if i've got anything wrong here...

Comment: Yes, you do. It's fraught with problems and you drew the schematic with a package that includes a simulator, so why not run the simulation and find out for yourself?

Comment: coz i don't know how to use one!! i simply breadboard these things and see if they work... i've always figured that learning to use a simulator would be too much of a drag... well, i did use the "Circuit-lab" package that is embeddable here in SE and i was even able to run a simulation, which spewed voltage and current probes i couldn't make sense of... and that was a real surprise to me... so maybe i could've bothered to learn an easy to use simulation software from the start... also, a "TVS diode" wasn't even in the list in the Circuit-lab package.

Comment: If you want to learn how to use a simulator, then LTspice is probably the place to start. It's free, it's powerful,and it comes with lots of models and sample circuits to get you started. Plus there are lots of tutorials on YouTube and a wonderful user group for help when you need it. The simulator is at: http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/   and the user group is at: http://groups.yahoo.com/group/LTspice/

Comment: Lol!  I realize this is an old thread, but it's funny that anyone would recommend LTspice to a beginner.  I don't see how the circuit could work.  The threshold of the Zener/TVS (same thing, no?) is still a positive resistance no matter how steep the curve.  To drain the cap requires a change of state in the circuit.  Otherwise the voltage will rise until the current in the base and collector equals the current in R1 and the circuit is stable, no "pulse".  Why can't anyone just answer the question rather than being oblique?

Answer (score 1):

Just for grins, here's a 555 astable with a duty cycle variable from about 1% to 99%, and if you choose to build it, C2 should be hooked directly across pins 1 and 8.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Zener is not connected as a Zener, but as a regular boring diode. The avalanche effect, or the Zener action, occurs when you *reverse bias* the diode. R2 protects the diode from damage from excessive current, and can be removed in this circuit as R3 conducts about 1mA/V, and it won't ever conduct more than 15mA.

I'd start as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6FCq2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can certainly use the 2N2222 transistor directly - you just need to select them for the avalanche breakdown. It's a common thing - you *are*, after all, depending on an aspect of their operation that is not the part of a normal production testing and the design isn't optimized to produce such effect reliably. 2N2222 pulsers work great - you just have to get a hundred transistors, 10 from each source, and check them out. You'll then identify what vendors and what parts produce the effect most reliably, then buy from them, and still qualify each part in a simple test rig (your circuit with a receptacle where you can plug the transistor - or on a solderless breadboard).

Comment: Running that, using the CircuitLab sim, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @EMFields I don't think that many simulators actually simulate the avalanche behavior. CircuitLab's simulation is completely messed up here, it doesn't even get startup conditions right (C1 should be discharged at start up). Remember: reality always trumps what a simulator tells you. Just try it out, and make sure you've got a bunch of different zeners to try out.

Comment: No thanks, I'd rather opt for something that works every time.

Comment: Huh??? I think you think I'm Badadeeboop.

Comment: @EMFields Yeah :) Sorry about that. I still stand by my rather poor opinion of CircuitLab's simulator. If it can't start up a simple RC circuit right, it's broken in my book.

Comment: oh, crap, i didn't notice that i got my avalanche diode in forward-bias... anyways, i've tried breadboarding this (the diode being reversed biased, and it doesn't produce a very steep high edge).

Comment: @Badadeeboop It's on *you* to select a diode that will work in this application, or use one that is *specified* to work. Just because the circuit looks "simple" doesn't mean it's useful in practice. You've just learned that, I hope.